# How can I use an ObservableObject as a Binding Target in code and XAML in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, binding, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, observableobject

How can I use an ObservableObject (from Community Toolkit) as a Binding Target in code and XAML in a WinUI 3 Desktop app?

Here's a simple (partial) homepage example:

```xaml
<!-- Home.xaml -->
<Page
    x:Class="PFSI.Views.Home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vms="using:PFSI.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >
    
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vms:HomeViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBox" Text="This text should be shaded." Foreground="{Binding Shade}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```c#
// Home.xaml.cs
public partial class HomePage : Page
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```c#
// HomeViewModel.cs
public class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        Classes.TraceListener.TraceMessage(GetType().Name);
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private SolidColorBrush shade;
}
```

Using the property Shade as a source is straightforward in XAML (see the TextBlock in Home.xaml) or in code:

```c#
Binding bBinding = new() { Path = new PropertyPath("Shade"), Source = ViewModel, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
TBox.SetBinding(TextBox.ForegroundProperty, bBinding);
```

But what if I want to make the property Shade the target of the binding (that is, I want to set Shade with the binding)?

`BindingOperations.SetBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)` requires a DependencyObject
(which HomeViewModel is not, it's an ObservableObject) and a DependencyProperty identifier (which Shade doesn't have as it's
a normal property).

I'm sure this is possible but I'm at a loss for the moment. Any help most welcome.

Comment: You seem to be looking for ``TwoWay`` binding. For example, a color picker control?

Comment: No, not at all, although I thought of that as a way to deal with this. I have an independent process that periodically produces a statistic. I'd like that statistic to set an ObservableProperty (the Target). The ObservableProperty may well be bound as a Source for other items in the model. The color was just an easy example. Thanks very much, though.

Comment: A target property of a binding must be a dependency property of a dependency object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use an ObservableObject (from Community Toolkit) as a Binding Target in code and XAML in a WinUI 3 Desktop app?

You can't since the target property of a binding must be a dependency property.

> I'm sure this is possible ...

Not without turning the target property into a dependency property (and the class into a `DependencyObject`).

I don't see why you would need to extend both `ObservableObject` and `DependencyObject` though. It's one or the other, i.e. either your class is some kind of view model or some kind of control.

Comment: Thank you. I know I couldn't find a way to target anything but a DependencyProperty with a binding (I also couldn't find anything that explicitly required one in a binding), but I wonder why? Wouldn't anything that notifies satisfy the binding requirements? As for my case, it's a ViewModel that I'd like to set in code.

Comment: Why? To enable the property to be tracked and influenced by the dedicated property system which for example includes just-in-time property determination mechanisms such as data binding, animations and storyboards.